# simulate asp:button click using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I try to activate my first buttons click/command using the second button
in order to activate my Login Command and Group Validation

what am I doing wrong?

first button

```
<asp:Button ID="LoginButtonInvis" runat="server"  CommandName="Login"
           ValidationGroup="Login1"
                visible ="false"/>
                </asp:Button>
```

second button

```
          <button name="submit" runat="server"onclick="document.getElementById('LoginButtonInvis').Click();">                
                <i class="icon-arrow-right icon-large"></i>
            </Button>
```

the error im getting:

`Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'Click': object is null or undefined`

Comment: why doing onclick="document.getElementById('LoginButtonInvis').Click();" are u trying to execute the function of LoginButtonInvis or trying to do a page load?

Comment: @jade I am trying to force the button execute the command

Comment: @NahumLitvin I think that you can not simulate the click - You can submit the form, you can call the onclick, but you can not actually simulate the click as the user make its.

Comment: @Aristos [yes he can](http://jsfiddle.net/7fhD8/1/). (click the second button, it will do its own stuff then simulate clicking the first button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, ASP.NET is appending parents ID's to controls to maintain unique ID to elements. This is proper behavior.

In addition, JavaScript is case sensitive. Events all start with small letters. Some browsers have `.click()` and others have `.onclick()` so the below code is the best I can offer without changes in other parts of your code:

```
onclick="var b = document.getElementById('<%=LoginButtonInvis.ClientID%>'); if (b.click) b.click(); else if (b.onclick) b.onclick();"
```

Also make sure the second button is not submit button by adding `type="button"` otherwise it will cause the form to be submitted twice.

Edit: this will work only if the first button is present in the document. With your current code, it's not present due to the `Visible="false"` you have. To send it while still keeping it hidden, remove the `Visible="false"` and add this in your code behind:

```
LoginButtonInvis.Style["display"] = "none";
```

Or alternatively apply CSS class with "display: none;" rule.

To avoid having inline JavaScript, plus better cross browser support (IE, yes) you better add JavaScript block in your page: (no matter where)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SimulateClick(buttonId) {
    var button = document.getElementById(buttonId);
    if (button) {
        if (button.click) {
            button.click();
        }
        else if (button.onclick) {
            button.onclick();
        }
        else {
            alert("DEBUG: button '" + buttonId + "' is not clickable");
        }
    } else {
        alert("DEBUG: button with ID '" + buttonId + "' does not exist");
    }
}
</script>
```

Now have only this in the second button:

```
<button name="submit" onclick="SimulateClick('<%=LoginButtonInvis.ClientID%>');"><i class="icon-arrow-right icon-large"></i></button>
```

Note also that you don't need `runat="server"` for the second button, it will just cause `<%=` to not work and complicate things.

Comment: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'click': object is null or undefined

Comment: That's because there is no first button.. having `visible="false"` on server side control means **it's not sent to the browser at all**. Going to update my answer shortly.

Comment: @Nahum if you remove the `Visible="false"` and have the first button showing it still doesn't work??

Comment: So you did something wrong. Check the HTML source or use browser tools to check what is the ID of the first button, what you see?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22835/discussion-between-nahum-litvin-and-shadow-wizard)

Comment: CLOSE! the LOGIN bUTTON IS INSIDE the freaking login control

Comment: Yeah, but the `<%=LoginButtonInvis.ClientID%>` should still find the actual ID. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try a different approach

On submit button click call a javascript and set a hidden variable field

```
function SetValue()
{
    //set hidden field value 
    form.submit();
}
```

Which will take the control to `page_load` event.In dere check the value of `hidden field` if it is set and execute the corresponding `LoginButtonInvis` command.And dont forget to reset the hidden field

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think the only problem with the original code is that the click method should all be in lower case:

`onclick="document.getElementById('LoginButtonInvis').click();`

Answer (score 0):

If it's a linkbutton, you can do this: `__doPostBack('ctl00$CP1$lnkBuscarEmpleado', '')`

I just found it while inspecting my button.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXeg3.png]